# How to check if writing to a file fails in Python

Tags: python

how can I print out a message if the action was successful?

For example:
I want to write a string to a file, and if everything was ok, it should print out an "ok" message. It is possible with an easy way?

Edit:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users'):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == '.'+ext:
            outfile = open('log.txt', 'w')
            outfile.write(fullpath)
            outfile.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your code?

Comment: `try/except`: Python 2 - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html, Python 3 - https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Also, for checking file extensions, you can use `fullpath.endswith(ext)`

Comment: I am not in the posibility to test now but have you tried this: 
    if  outfile.write(fullpath)
        print "ok"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: python will tell you if there's an error.  Otherwise, it is safe to assume everything is working (provided your code is correct)

For example:

```
a = "some string"
print "Variable set! a = ", a
```

would verify that the line `a = "some string"` executed without error.

You could make this more explicit like so:

```
try:
  a = "some string"
  print "Success!"
except:
  print "Error detected!"
```

But this is bad practice.  It is unnecessarily verbose, and the exception will print a more useful error message anyway.