# Implement file in python program?

Tags: python

```
 f=open('foo.dat','w+')
 rate=0
 print"Menu is:"
 print"""1. Indian
           2.Italian
           3.Chinese
           4.COntinential
           5.Starters and drinks"""
 hotel_food={1:'Indian',2:'Italian',3:'Chinese'}
 f.write(str(hotel_food))
 food=input("Enter the food type:")
 f.write(str(food))
 if(hotel_food.has_key(food)):
      print"Menu is:"
      print"""1. Roti with Curry
           2.South Indian Cuisines
           3.festival dishes
           4.sea food"""
      hotel_food1={1:'Roti with Curry',
           2:'South Indian Cuisines'}
      f.write(str(hotel_food1))
      fd=input("ENter the food type")
      f.write(str(fd))
      if(hotel_food1.has_key(fd)):
            rate=rate+1234
            print rate

  l=f.write(str(rate))

  x=f.read(l)
  print x

 f.close()
```

This program allows user to input the type of food they want and the subtype as well. after that the bill or rate is calculated.

When I run the program, the error is:     `x=f.read(l)`
TypeError: an integer is required

but when I make it into : `x=f.read(str(l))`
the same error comes: `x=f.read(str(l))`
TypeError: an integer is required.

Here, only one case is shown even though the menu has 5 cases, that is selecting Indian food and roti with curry. If this gets correct, I will do the rest.

Is this the right way to implement files in python? I can't write anything into file.

Comment: That's not how you use [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). 

The parameter to `read` lets you specify a certain amount of bytes to read from the file.

Comment: i want to print rate just to check whether its written into file.how do you check it?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here: `x=f.read(l)`

When you pass a single argument to `read()` is expects and integer (how many bytes to read IIRC).

Use `x=f.read()` with no argument to read all data from the file.

Also `l=f.write(str(rate))` is unnecessary.   Just call `f.write(str(rate))`  no need to store return value, unless you're expecting something to go wrong.

**EDIT:**  I have a few recommendations:  Use a string rather than an int and a key for your dictionaries.  This way `raw_input()` will provide a key you can use directly.

Also, you are reading a writing to the same file too often, it is messing up your reading.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) for more pythonic handling of files.  I would recommend encapsulating your reads and write this way.

If you just want to check that you have written the data to a file, simply use `f.write(data)` and **assume it work unless it throws an error.**  See my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731841/how-to-check-if-writing-to-a-file-fails-in-python/31731966#31731966)

I'm not entirely sure what is supposed to happen, but here is my best guess

```
f=open('foo.dat','w+')
rate=0
print"Menu is:"
print"""1. Indian
        2.Italian
        3.Chinese
        4.COntinential
        5.Starters and drinks"""
hotel_food={'1':'Indian','2':'Italian','3':'Chinese'}
f.write(str(hotel_food))
food=raw_input("Enter the food type: ")
f.write(str(food))
if(food in hotel_food):
    print"Menu is:"
    print"""1. Roti with Curry
    2.South Indian Cuisines
    3.festival dishes
    4.sea food"""
    hotel_food1={'1':'Roti with Curry', '2':'South Indian Cuisines'}
    f.write(str(hotel_food1))
    fd=raw_input("ENter the food type: ")
    f.write(str(fd))
    if fd in hotel_food1:
        rate=rate+1234
        f.write(str(rate))
        x=f.read()
        print x

f.close()
```

Hope this help!

Comment: can you help me with the indentation of these required lines?? and here to check whether rate is written into file, i want these statements.just to print rate.

Comment: It did not work but thank you so much for your time and effort.